# Jackson: Stream JSON array via databinding?

Tags: json, data-binding, jackson, streaming

I have a JSON file with a structure like this:

```
[
    obj1,
    obj2,
    ...
    objN
]
```

All of the sub-objects are entirely self-contained, i.e. there are no cross references between them. The problem is that the file as a whole is huge ( >100k entries in the root array).

Is there any way in Jackson to stream in the contents of the root array via databinding, such that the root array never resides fully in main memory? I would like to avoid the low level JsonGenerator/JsonParser API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Check out `ObjectReader` (constructed using various methods in `ObjectMapper`, like `.readerFor(ElementType.class)`), and then its `readValues()` method, which returns `MappingIterator<ElementType>` (for whatever type you use). This method will only bind one item at a time.

If the values are in root-level array, this should work as is. If they were somewhere deeper in JSON structure, you would have to construct `JsonParser` first, then iterate (with `nextToken()`) to the first value, but after that you could still create `MappingIterator` for efficient item-by-item binding.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the hint I needed to get started!